# Scoring a confusing cribbage hand

Tags: cribbage

My father and his friend were playing cribbage today and ran into a dilemma trying to score their hand properly.  Could you let me know what you think so I can straighten this out for them.  The hand was 3 Aces and 2 Sevens.  How is this hand scored?

I do not play cribbage and therefore could offer no help to their situation.

Answer (score 6):

You have three A's, let's call them AC, AS, AH (no diamond), and two 7's, let's say 7C and 7S.

- First, you have 6 points in 15s: 7C/7S/AC, 7C/7S/AS and 7C/7S/AH.
- You have no runs or double runs.
- Next, you have 6 points in Ace pairs: AC/AS, AC/AH, and AC/AH (also known as a Pair Royal).
- Next, you have 2 points in Seven pairs: 7C/7S.
- You have no flushes.
- You have no Jacks for his nobs.

This is a total of 6+2+6=14.

Comment: thxs so much for your help. That's exactly what my father thought but his friend was sure it was 16!  Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a web page that you can use to score any cribbage hand:

http://www.bucktheodds.com/cribbage/score

And, here is your specific hand

http://www.bucktheodds.com/cribbage/score?cardsText=1D,1H,1S,7D,7S

The page is really cool because it shows a list of all scoring combinations:

```
Scoring Details
15 Count    1H,7S,7D    6
            1S,7S,7D    
            1D,7S,7D    
Pairs       1H,1S,1D    8
            7S,7D
Straights               0
Jack                    0
Flush                   0
Total                   14
```

Comment: Why the negative votes? These links will help people with difficult scoring questions.